# How to find which PPAs to purge when upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, ppa, do-release-upgrade

I am upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.1 using the `sudo do-release-upgrade` command.

At some point I got the following message:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.
```

The tool, `ppa-purge` requires to provide specific `ppaname` or `ppaowner` as input.

How do I know which PPA is actually causing the upgrade issues?

Comment: I recommend that you remove all but official sources and reinstall any unofficial sources after a successful upgrade

Comment: Open up Software and Updates and all PPAs you added will be under other software tab.  Uncheck all and reload, need password.

Comment: Meant uncheck all the PPAs, leave the others alone.

Comment: Start `synaptic` (install it if you need to), and click the RELOAD button. The error(s) that appear are the problem. Show me the errors (copy/paste into your question) and I can try to help.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, I already followed the previous advice and disabled all PPAs from the update manager GUI. I have now an unresolvable error with no explanation at all, but this is probably a material for a different question.

Comment: @heynnema If you post this as an answer, maybe with some additional explanation on how to deduce the packages from the error messages of synaptic, I will happily accept it since it answers the question exactly.

Comment: Screenshot the current error and let me take a look. This error is from Synaptic?

Comment: @heynnema https://i.stack.imgur.com/V483u.png Synaptic does not err probably because I disabled the PPAs. Anyway, it is too much hassle to solve one tiny problem after another. I think I will go on the path of full reinstall rather than an upgrade.

Comment: Sounds good! Cheers!